# Extracting posterior modes and credible intervals from glmmTMB output

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, credible-interval, glmmtmb

I normally work with `lme4` package, but the `glmmTMB` package is increasingly becoming better suited to work with highly complicated data (think overdispersion and/or zero-inflation).

> **Is there a way to extract posterior modes and credible intervals from `glmmTMB` models,** similar to how it is done for `lme4` models (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022246/extract-posterior-estimate-and-credible-intervals-for-random-effect-for-lme4-mod)).

Details:

I am working with count data (available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d)) that are zero-inflated and overdispersed and have random effects. The package best suited to work with this sort of data is the `glmmTMB` (details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/glmmTMB.pdf)). (Note two outliers: `euc0==78` and `np_other_grass==20`).

The data looks like this:

```
euc0 ea_grass ep_grass np_grass np_other_grass month year precip season   prop_id quad
 3      5.7      0.0     16.7            4.0     7 2006    526 Winter    Barlow    1
 0      6.7      0.0     28.3            0.0     7 2006    525 Winter    Barlow    2
 0      2.3      0.0      3.3            0.0     7 2006    524 Winter    Barlow    3
 0      1.7      0.0     13.3            0.0     7 2006    845 Winter    Blaber    4
 0      5.7      0.0     45.0            0.0     7 2006    817 Winter    Blaber    5
 0     11.7      1.7     46.7            0.0     7 2006    607 Winter    DClark    3
```

The `glmmTMB` model:

```
model<-glmmTMB(euc0 ~ ea_grass + ep_grass + np_grass + np_other_grass + (1|prop_id), data = euc, family= nbinom2) #nbimom2 lets var increases quadratically
summary(model)
confint(model) #this gives the confidence intervals
```

How I would normally extract the posterior mode and credible intervals for a `lmer`/`glmer` model:

```
#extracting model estimates and credible intervals
sm.model <-arm::sim(model, n.sim=1000)
smfixef.model = sm.model@fixef
smfixef.model =coda::as.mcmc(smfixef.model)
MCMCglmm::posterior.mode(smfixef.model)  #mode of the distribution
coda::HPDinterval(smfixef.model)  #credible intervals

#among-brood variance
bid<-sm.model@ranef$prop_id[,,1]
bvar<-as.vector(apply(bid, 1, var)) #between brood variance posterior distribution
bvar<-coda::as.mcmc(bvar)
MCMCglmm::posterior.mode(bvar) #mode of the distribution
coda::HPDinterval(bvar) #credible intervals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of an answer:

1. Getting a multivariate Normal sample of the parameters of the conditional model is pretty easy (I *think* this is what `arm::sim()` is doing.

```
library(MASS)
pp <- fixef(model)$cond
vv <- vcov(model)$cond
samp <- MASS::mvrnorm(1000, mu=pp, Sigma=vv)
```

(then use the rest of your method above).

2. I'm a little skeptical that your second example is doing what you want it to do. The variance of the conditional modes is *not necessarily a good estimate of the between-group variance* (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275620/why-is-the-estimated-variance-of-a-random-effect-not-equal-to-the-variance-of-it)).  Furthermore, I'm nervous about the half-assed-Bayesian approach (e.g., why no priors? Why look at the posterior mode, which is rarely a meaningful value in a Bayesian context?) although I do sometimes use similar approaches myself!) However, it's not *too* hard to use glmmTMB results to do a proper Markov chain Monte Carlo analysis:

```
library(tmbstan)
library(rstan)
library(coda)
library(emdbook) ## for lump.mcmc.list(), or use runjags::combine.mcmc()

t2 <- system.time(m2 <- tmbstan(model$obj))
m3 <- rstan::As.mcmc.list(m2)
lattice::xyplot(m3,layout=c(5,6))
m4 <- emdbook::lump.mcmc.list(m3)
coda::HPDinterval(m4)
```

It may be helpful to know that the `theta` column of `m4` is the log of the among-group standard standard deviation ...

(See `vignette("mcmc", package="glmmTMB")` for a little bit more information ...)

Comment: Just for the record, samples of parameters can be easily obtained (with literally the same underlying code) from [`parameters::simulate_model()`](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/simulate_model.html) resp. for the summary [`parameters::simulate_parameters()`](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/simulate_parameters.html) (including nice [`plot()`-methods](https://easystats.github.io/see/articles/parameters.html)).

Comment: I spent some time looking at the vignette you linked to. I still don't fully understand the output for your `t2`, `m3`, and `m4`. Would it be possible to annotate the code a bit to help me understand what each function is doing/showing?

Answer (score 1):

I think Ben has already answered your question, so my answer does not add much to the discussion... Maybe just one thing, as you wrote in your comments that you're interested in the within- and between-group variances. You can get these information via `parameters::random_parameters()` (if I did not misunderstand what you were looking for). See example below that first generates simulated samples from a multivariate normal (just like in Ben's example), and later gives you a summary of the random effect variances...

```r
library(readr)
library(glmmTMB)
library(parameters)
library(bayestestR)
library(insight)

euc_data <- read_csv("D:/Downloads/euc_data.csv")
model <-
  glmmTMB(
    euc0 ~ ea_grass + ep_grass + np_grass + np_other_grass + (1 | prop_id),
    data = euc_data,
    family = nbinom2
  ) #nbimom2 lets var increases quadratically


# generate samples
samples <- parameters::simulate_model(model)
#> Model has no zero-inflation component. Simulating from conditional parameters.


# describe samples
bayestestR::describe_posterior(samples)
#> # Description of Posterior Distributions
#> 
#> Parameter      | Median |           89% CI |    pd |        89% ROPE | % in ROPE
#> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)    | -1.072 | [-2.183, -0.057] | 0.944 | [-0.100, 0.100] |     1.122
#> ea_grass       | -0.001 | [-0.033,  0.029] | 0.525 | [-0.100, 0.100] |   100.000
#> ep_grass       | -0.050 | [-0.130,  0.038] | 0.839 | [-0.100, 0.100] |    85.297
#> np_grass       | -0.020 | [-0.054,  0.012] | 0.836 | [-0.100, 0.100] |   100.000
#> np_other_grass | -0.002 | [-0.362,  0.320] | 0.501 | [-0.100, 0.100] |    38.945


# or directly get summary of sample description
sp <- parameters::simulate_parameters(model, ci = .95, ci_method = "hdi", test = c("pd", "p_map"))
sp
#> Model has no zero-inflation component. Simulating from conditional parameters.
#> # Description of Posterior Distributions
#> 
#> Parameter      | Coefficient | p_MAP |    pd |              CI
#> --------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)    |      -1.037 | 0.281 | 0.933 | [-2.305, 0.282]
#> ea_grass       |      -0.001 | 0.973 | 0.511 | [-0.042, 0.037]
#> ep_grass       |      -0.054 | 0.553 | 0.842 | [-0.160, 0.047]
#> np_grass       |      -0.019 | 0.621 | 0.802 | [-0.057, 0.023]
#> np_other_grass |       0.019 | 0.999 | 0.540 | [-0.386, 0.450]

plot(sp) + see::theme_modern()
#> Model has no zero-inflation component. Simulating from conditional parameters.
```

[image]

```r
# random effect variances
parameters::random_parameters(model)
#> # Random Effects
#> 
#> Within-Group Variance         2.92 (1.71)
#> Between-Group Variance
#>   Random Intercept (prop_id)   2.1 (1.45)
#> N (groups per factor)
#>   prop_id                       18
#> Observations                   346

insight::get_variance(model)
#> Warning: mu of 0.2 is too close to zero, estimate of random effect variances may be unreliable.
#> $var.fixed
#> [1] 0.3056285
#> 
#> $var.random
#> [1] 2.104233
#> 
#> $var.residual
#> [1] 2.91602
#> 
#> $var.distribution
#> [1] 2.91602
#> 
#> $var.dispersion
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $var.intercept
#>  prop_id 
#> 2.104233
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think I must be missing something. When I get to the `parameters::random_parameters(model)` line, I get an error: 'random_parameters' is not an exported object from 'namespace:parameters'. Is there a package I should be loading beforehand? Everything else runs well.

Comment: Also, some points of clarification. Is the `bayestestR::describe_posterior()` output analogous to the way I was extracting posterior modes for the fixed effects and credible intervals? What is the difference between this and the output from `parameters::simulate_parameters()`?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions... What object is called `sp` for your plot?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I think you just need to update the parameters-package from CRAN (must be version 0.7.0). `bayestestR::describe_posterior()` just takes a Bayesian model, or a data frame (this is what you get from `arm::sim()` or `parameters::simulate_model()`, which literally does something very similar like arm::sin) and gives you some information on the distribution of the (posterior) samples. However, `bayestestR::describe_posterior()` does no extract the samples from a frequentist model, the samples you get from arm::sim or parameters::simulate_model.

Comment: `parameters::simulate_parameters()` is a kind of combination of parameters::simulate_model (or arm::sim) and bayestestR::describe_posterior. It first calls internally simulate_model() to get the samples, and then calls describe_posterior() to give you the "summary information". Regarding `sp`: sorry, I accidentally deleted two lines of code, will edit the example.

Comment: Thank you for those points of clarification. One additional follow-up:  so, while the output for `bayestestR::describe_posterior()` and `parameters::simulate_parameters()` are similar, `parameters::simulate_parameters()` extracts samples from a frequentist model?

Comment: > parameters::simulate_parameters() extracts samples from a frequentist model?
Yes, by calling simulate_model(), which [uses this code](https://github.com/easystats/parameters/blob/1d0ca173d0ae242e96728a67bfb209d89dae3f85/R/simulate_model.R#L441) to generate a multivariate normal sample of the parameters (you'll see that the code is fairly similar to what Ben posted, just that it's more generic and works for many other models, not only lme4/glmmTMB, as well).